# Is there another way to resize Blockly workspace?

Tags: css, blockly

I am trying to adapt my `Blockly workspace` inside a div. I want that if the page makes smaller, the div and the `Blockly workspace` inside of it would be smaller also.

I know that there is a way that `Google` provides in its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/injecting-resizable#positioning) but I think it is a bit "dirty" and you have to use a lot of code to resize it.

Looking at the debugger of `Google Chrome` I saw that I can set a `max-height` to the `svg` object but I do not know how to change that `height` when you inject the workspace:

```
var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
    {toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
```

Anyway, it will not solve my problem at all (just avoid that the workspace would be bigger than the div before resizing the page).

I also tried changing my `blocklyDiv` in which I inject the `Blockly workspace` to `display: flex;` but it does not change anything.

Is there a better approach than `Google's` example to resize the `Blockly workspace`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link or JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @darrylyeo I can create one, but I do not know how to add Blockly to it.

Comment: I use a simple "width: 100px" in the blockly div and it resizes ok. Of course, if the blocks does not fit in the workspace, then there will be scroll bars to allow moving inside it... I understand that is not what you want? Maybe you want to change the scale of the blocks to make them fit in the provided space?

Comment: @jrierab But I want that at the same time I resize the screen, the workspace will be also resized. With a fixed width I cannot do that. If the blocks could be resized at the same time it would be great!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I was saying "width: 100%", that is, relative to the parent div. And it effectively resizes the workspace, but maybe it works because I have a fixed height? In any case, you could add an image showing what is wrong and what you expect to achieve.

Comment: @jrierab Do you know how can I add `Blockly` to a JSFiddle? If it is possible I can do one to play with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in above comment, I allow width resize while fixing the height in the blockly div.

```
<div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 800px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Here you have the JSFiddle to play with:
[blockly workspace resizing](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ojjwkL/).

Comment: It looks good. Can you please provide a detailed answer of how do you do it? As I can see, you have used a lot of parameters when you inject the code that I had never seen before.

Comment: No need for any special parameters for your purposes (only the toolbox option is really needed). Zoom options are specified here: https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/zoom#controls. They allow to use the mouse wheel (or  the semi-transparent icons) for zoom in/out in the workspace.

Answer (score 5):

I used CSS Only to get the same behavior...

Just create a container for the blockly editor with any size you want and position relative, then put a blockly editor inside with position absolute.

HTML Code:

```
<section id="blocklyContainer">
    <div id="blocklyDiv"></div>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
#blocklyContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#blocklyDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here you have a CodePen to see: [blockly resize](https://codepen.io/juanialt/pen/prvzom)

Comment: It seems that adding categories.... it does not show side-panel anymore...

Comment: @LucaDetomi I have updated the codepen example for you with two random categories. It's working also, can you take a look? thanks!

Comment: No Juan, I tried to programmatically change width of `blocklyContainer` (you can do it also from Inspector) and size of canvas is not changed until you force a browser window resize... So the problem remains: how to change Blockly canvas size changing ONLY size of a DIV container, not changing browser window size?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using Blockly.svgResize api, note that if the size changes with transition, you have to set a timeout function and  call the api in the callback in timeout, the delay is the transition time.