# Preventing the Blockly toolbox from being zoomed

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

When zooming in and out on the workspace the toolbox will also zoom which causes the blocks to increase/decrease in size.

Is there anyway to prevent zooming on the toolbox and its blocks, yet still allow for the workspace to be zoomed?

Comment: I guess they intentionally keep sizes of blocks in toolbar and workspace in sync. This avoids "size jump" when you drag block from toolbar.

Comment: I'd also like to know if there's a way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You may check the documentation of blockly while setting workspace,
  Following url  may show you zoom properties and how to use it [clickHere](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/zoom)

Comment: you can check following url also -- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837896/is-there-another-way-to-resize-blockly-workspace?rq=1]